# Error : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r

I have changed a little bit my R code that worked perfectly,but instead 3 now I have 7 clusters.

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5), ncol=1))

# main plots
par(mai=rep(0.5, 4))

fcm <-c(14.0,14.1,13.0,14.2,14.7,13.8,14.0)
gk  <-c(12.1,12.5,12.2,12.0,11.5,12.0,11.4)
gg  <-c(14.0,14.1,13.3,12.8,12.0,12.2,12.0)
data1 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data1) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

fcm <-c(2.65,2.55,2.4,2.45,2.45,2.5,2.45)
gk  <-c(2.45,2.55,2.4,2.3,2.2,2.35,2.1)
gg  <-c(2.6,2.65,2.5,2.35,2.4,2.4,2.2)
data2 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data2) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

fcm <-c(8.8,6.5,6.6,8.2,8.0,8.4,9.0)
gk  <-c(12.7,11.0,11.1,10.5,10.7,10.0,9.5)
gg  <-c(2.1,2.1,1.8,2.0,2.0,1.9,1.8)
data3 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data3) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

fcm <-c(0.47,0.53,0.45,0.39,0.40,0.47,0.48)
gk  <-c(0.45,0.51,0.34,0.40,0.42,0.42,0.44)
data4 <- rbind(fcm,gk)
colnames(data4) <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

barplot(as.matrix(data1),ylim=c(0,20),main="P wave",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data2),ylim=c(0,2),main="MT",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="MT functions",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data3),ylim=c(0,20),main="XBI",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="index value",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data4),ylim=c(0,0.6),main="NCE",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="index value",
        col=c("red", "black"), beside=TRUE)

par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
legend(legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), fill = c( "red", "black", "green"), 
    "center", horiz=TRUE)
```

But then I got

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

The problem is with the rbind.I am combining 3 vectors,each of them has 7 elements.What should I change?I want that each element has the proper number of clusters labeled behind.

Comment: So we have to load all this code to figure out where the error occurred?  Here's your problem `ncol(data1) == length(c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12)) ## [1] FALSE`.  Closing as typo.

Comment: @RichardScriven I do not know,I have made a change from 3 to 7 clusters.

Comment: Please see my edited comment.

Comment: No, it's simple: There are eight columns and only seven names are provided.

Comment: @RHertel Sorry I still do not get,I just see 7 columns.

Comment: @RHertel Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply one more column name. Your data has eight columns, as can be seen, e.g., with

```
> length(fcm)
[1] 8
```

or

```
> ncol(data1)
[1] 8
```

or by displaying the matrix:

```
> data1
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#fcm 14.0 14.1 13.0   14  2.0 14.7 13.8 14.0
#gk  12.1 12.5 12.2   12  0.0 11.5 12.0 11.4
#gg  14.0 14.1 13.0    3 12.8 12.0 12.2 12.0
```

while

```
> length( c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
[1] 7
```

You could try with

```
colnames(data1) <- c(6:13)
```

With your data, this would be:

```
fcm <-c(14.0,14.1,13.0,14,2,14.7,13.8,14.0)
gk  <-c(12.1,12.5,12.2,12,0,11.5,12.0,11.4)
gg  <-c(14.0,14.1,13,3,12.8,12.0,12.2,12.0)
data1 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data1) <- c(6:13)
```

which gives:

```
> data1
       6    7    8  9   10   11   12   13
fcm 14.0 14.1 13.0 14  2.0 14.7 13.8 14.0
gk  12.1 12.5 12.2 12  0.0 11.5 12.0 11.4
gg  14.0 14.1 13.0  3 12.8 12.0 12.2 12.0
```

without any error message.

Comment: No,changing colnmames(data1) does not solve the problem.Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 6:13) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Comment: The other matrices, data2, data3, and data4 have 7 columns. There the definition with `colnames()` using `c(6:12)` is alright. However, data 1 is a matrix in your set with eight columns. Either one column needs to be removed, or the numbering with `colnames()` must be adapted.

Comment: @RHertel I have changed data1,it has 7 columns now.Still I got the same error.

Comment: @RichardRublev Where did you change it? The data posted in the OP still contains 8 columns for `data1`.

Comment: @RHertel Try now,please.

Comment: @RichardRublev In your edited post you have changed the data so that data1 now contains seven columns, so your original code with `colnames()` using `c(6:12)` should work now.

Comment: @RichardRublev I can run your code now without any error message. I think we can close this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89188/discussion-between-richard-rublev-and-rhertel).