# Renaming header for column in R

Tags: r

I have imported a data set from R using the quantmod function and one of the columns does not have a header. I tried giving it a header name because I am trying to run a regression over time.

I got the error below:

> `Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`

This is the full code I ran:

```
# To load data from FRED 

library(quantmod)
getSymbols('DAUTONSA',src='FRED')`

## Subset data as you wish: remove observations after February 2019

date.start <- "1967-01-01"
date.end <- "2019-02-01"
AUTOdata <-DAUTONSA[paste(date.start,date.end,sep="/")]
View(AUTOdata)

summary(AUTOdata)
plot(AUTOdata)

# Changing names of data
data.frame(AUTOdata)
names(AUTOdata) <- c("time", "sales")
```

This is when I got the error function

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: It would be better to give us some sample data that replicates your problem. Still, judging by what you've written, it looks like your Autodata object does not have 2 columns. This might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464829/error-length-of-dimnames-2-not-equal-to-array-extent

Comment: Are there only two columns in 'AUTOdata'?

Comment: The first column isn't actually a column. You could try something like `data.frame(time= index(AUTOdata), coredata(AUTOdata))` and then rename

Answer (score 1):

`AUTOdata` is not a data.frame.

```
class(AUTOdata)
#[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

It does not have 2 columns

```
dim(AUTOdata)
#[1] 626   1
```

You can convert the data into data.frame

```
df <- zoo::fortify.zoo(AUTOdata)
```

and then rename the columns

```
names(df) <- c("time", "sales")
head(df)
#        time sales
#1 1967-01-01 564.1
#2 1967-02-01 509.1
#3 1967-03-01 670.4
#4 1967-04-01 710.2
#5 1967-05-01 744.8
#6 1967-06-01 780.2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. My only concern was that, I was wondering if converting the time series data into a data frame would have any effect on me making forecasts or any estimations. Also when I run the code on my end, the formats of the dates changed, so now I only have negative numbers instead of dates

Comment: @LauraA If you don't want to convert it into dataframe, you can do `names(AUTOdata) <- "sales"`